# Web API HttpClient PutAsync returning Http 404

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, dotnet-httpclient

Im trying to send a PUT to my Web API and am struggling a bit as to how I should construct the actual Http request. Below is an integration test sample. It works fine using HttpMessageInvoker to call the Web API Put, but I want to use HttpClient in test also since that is what I'll be using in the business layer.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Verify_UpdateBudgetData_Http_PUT()
    {
        int budgetId = 1;
        string appId = "DummyApp";
        string userId = "Dummy";
        string value = "400";
        string filterJSON =
                "{dimensionFilter:{\"Demo_Konto\":[\"3000\"],\"Demo_AO\":[\"200\"]},valueSpreadType:{\"Value1\":0}}";

        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
        Konstrukt.SL.AggregationEngine.WebApiConfig.Register(config, new SL.AggregationEngine.AutofacStandardModule());
        HttpServer server = new HttpServer(config);

        /*this works*/
        using (HttpMessageInvoker client = new HttpMessageInvoker(server))
        {
            using (HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, 
                String.Format("http://localhost/AggregationEngine/UpdateBudgetData/{0}/{1}/{2}/{3}/{4}",
                budgetId, appId, userId, value, filterJSON)))
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(request, CancellationToken.None).Result)
            {
                Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode, "Wrong http status returned");
            }
        };

        /*this does not work*/
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            //client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            var responseMessage =
                client.PutAsync(
                    String.Format("http://localhost/AggregationEngine/UpdateBudgetData/{0}/{1}/{2}/{3}/{4}",
                        budgetId, appId, userId, value, filterJSON), new StringContent("")).Result;
            Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, responseMessage.StatusCode, "Wrong http status returned");
        }
    }
```

Here is my WebApiConfig-class

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config, Autofac.Module moduleToAppend)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "UpdateBudgetData",
            routeTemplate: "AggregationEngine/{controller}/{budgetId}/{appId}/{userId}/{value}/{filterJSON}",
            defaults: new { filter = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "GetBudgetAndRefData",
            routeTemplate: "AggregationEngine/{controller}/{budgetId}/{userId}/{filterJSON}",
            defaults: new { filter = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.EnableCors();
        config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();

        // Autofac container
        // if not configured here you'll not have dependencies provided to your WebApiControllers when called
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder(); // yes, it is a different container here

        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes( // register Web API Controllers
            Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
                .Where(t =>
                    !t.IsAbstract && typeof(ApiController).IsAssignableFrom(t))
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        // register your graph - shared
        builder.RegisterModule(
            new AutofacStandardModule()); // same as with ASP.NET MVC Controllers

        if (moduleToAppend != null)
        {
            builder.RegisterModule(moduleToAppend);
        }

        var container = builder.Build();

        config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(
            container);
    }

    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        Register(config, null);
    }
}
```

How can I fix the HttpClient call to PutAsync? Should I embed the FilterJSON parameter in the body? If so, how to do that? I've tried that but then the FromBody parametger was null...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by using the FromBody tag in the controller and then wrapping that parameter in the http request body. An important note to is to prefix the parameter with an "=" sign to make sure it was interpreted correctly by the controller. Also I removed the same parameter from the route config. Finally to make the client to server request work I had to replace HttpServer Class with httpselfhostserver